# Introduction to Rashee numbers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, palindrome

**Definition**: A Rashee number is an integer that can form a palindrome through the iterative process of repeatedly reversing its digits and subtracting  the resulting numbers.

To check if the number $3226$ is a Rashee number or not:

$3226 \to (3226-6223) = -2997 \to (-2997+7992)=4995 \to (4995-5994)=-999$

So yes, $3226$ is a Rashee number.

> > 1) give one example of non-Rashee number in base-$10$?
> >
> > 2) show that there are infinitely many Rashee numbers in base-$10$?
> >
> > 3) show that there are infinitely many non-Rashee numbers in base-$10$?

Does the idea of this Rashee number already exist? Is it as hard as proving [Lychrel number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) $2178$ is NOT a Rashee number:
$$2178 \to (2178-8712)=-6534 \to (-6534+4356)=-2178\\
\to (-2178+8712)=6534 \to (6534-4356)=2178$$
and we have a cycle. Another one is, of course, $6534$.

2) Any palindromic number is a Rashee number so they are infinite. Also $2\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n$ times}}1$ is a Rashee number:
$$2\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n$ times}}1 \to (2\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n$ times}}1-1\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n$ times}}2)=\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n+1$ times}}.$$

3) It is easy to verify that $21\underbrace{99\dots 9}_{\text{$n$ times}}78$ is NOT a Rashee number and therefore there are infinitely many non-Rashee numbers.

Comment: @Pruthviraj Any comment from your side?

Comment: great, you done it. I'm  going to more genialize this processes, any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe this paper could be of some help:  https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/28-2/cohn.pdf